# Android - Call log/ history : Retrieve a dialed number when there was no network coverage

Tags: call-history

I dialed a number when I had no network support but it does not appear in the call history of my android phone.

Is there any way to get it ? (system logs or whatever)

THanks a lot in advance,
Jack

Comment: A dup: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14795/any-way-to-retrieve-phone-number-dialed-while-in-airplane-mode

Answer (score 3):

Your phone deals with three types of calls: `incoming`, `outgoing` or `missed`. As you can see from the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#TYPE).

Technically speaking, you've typed some digits, but since you had no network coverage, you didn't actually place any call. So, there was no reason to log anything, or even a way to classify those digits as a valid outgoing call.

Android has a database to store all the calls made, but they must match one of the above three types, and as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html) the existent fields on the database don't contemplate the possibility of  rows for every collection of digits typed that doesn't fit the parameters of a call (duration, type, etc..).