# Any way to retrieve phone number dialed while in airplane mode?

Tags: calls, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Call log/ history : Retrieve a dialed number when there was no network coverage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10922/android-call-log-history-retrieve-a-dialed-number-when-there-was-no-network)

I dialed a new phone number while in airplane mode, and the number was not saved. Is there any way to restore this number from any logs or maybe some combination?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you're out of luck. Android doesn't appear to save to the Call Log a number that failed to go through. AFAIK that's the only place where it might have been recorded.

Comment: Dup is here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10922/android-call-log-history-retrieve-a-dialed-number-when-there-was-no-network